# How do I add a custom 2010 VSTO Office Runtime for InstallShield LE?

Tags: c#, vsto, installshield

I'm trying to create a VSTO using an InstallSheild installer.  I've followed the instructions [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc442767.aspx#Configure) for creating a custom redistributable version of 2010 VSTO.  However, when I refresh the list, the new custom `.prq` doesn't show up.  How do I create a custom `.prq` that will show up in the list of redistributables?

Here is the xml code I used to create the custom prereq:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
<conditions>
    <condition Type="32" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R" FileName="Version" ReturnValue="10.0.40309" Bits="2"></condition>
</conditions>
<files>
    <file LocalFile="<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\VSTOR\vstor_redist.exe" URL="http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/1/B51D2F9E-1432-4B76-8248-F47316BB8EE0/vstor_redist.exe" CheckSum="a1b5c8fb246a9d0d66f12d3b6f5e471d" FileSize="0,40051808"></file>
</files>
<execute file="vstor_redist.exe" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1">
</execute>
<properties Id="{3A84D56D-8682-4CAC-925E-3F1BDF3BE700}" Description="This prerequisite installs the most recent version of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime." >
</properties>

</SetupPrereq>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a small typo in it under a file in the files section:

```
<files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\VSTOR\vstor_redist.exe" URL="http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/1/B51D2F9E-1432-4B76-8248-F47316BB8EE0/vstor_redist.exe" CheckSum="a1b5c8fb246a9d0d66f12d3b6f5e471d" FileSize="0,40051808"></file>
</files>
```

The `&lt;` and `&gt;` are necessary since (I assume) they are parsed into the `<` and `>` as the tool refreshes the data.

---

<sup>Note: I assumed that from copying and pasting the code from the website, that these were incorrectly pasted, as sometimes this does happen.  In this case, however, this is necessary</sup>

Comment: They should seriously include this in the docs...  it's obvious once you see it, but when you are trying to follow those instructions to the letter (which are quite extensive), it's easy to miss something like this